# Using strsplit to split my data into a dataframe

Tags: r, regex

Apologies if this has been asked before but I just wanted to explore if filtering out my data from this format can be done using `strsplit` on the '=' symbol. To do this everytime we see the '=' symbol we take the info either side of it, this would look something like the data frame at the bottom of the question. I originally tried using a gsub method to extract my data here but as the '=' stays consistent throughout I thought it might be better to use this. I'm also not too sure how it would treat parts which are blank.

```
mystring <- 'nameinfo=Joe, Bloggs [[UK gender=2 id1=6.2 id2=7 id=3 id4= id5=0 total=20.6'
```

what I'm trying to achieve:

```
mydf
nameinfo=Joe, Bloggs [[UK 
gender=2 
id1=6.2 
id2=7 
id=3
id4= 
id5=0 
total=20.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lookahead as the separator in `strsplit()`:

```r
data.frame(x = unlist(strsplit(mystring, "\\s(?=\\S*=)", perl = TRUE)))
#                           x
# 1 nameinfo=Joe, Bloggs [[UK
# 2                  gender=2
# 3                   id1=6.2
# 4                     id2=7
# 5                      id=3
# 6                      id4=
# 7                     id5=0
# 8                total=20.6
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R.

Note that use a character for sep that does not exist in your data. eg: `sep = '+'`

```
read.table(text=gsub(' (?=\\w+=)', "\n", mystring, perl = TRUE), sep = '{')
                         V1
1 nameinfo=Joe, Bloggs [[UK
2                  gender=2
3                   id1=6.2
4                     id2=7
5                      id=3
6                      id4=
7                     id5=0
8                total=20.6
```

If you want two columns, use `sep = '='`

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to zephryl's answer but slightly different regex.

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(x = unlist(str_split_1(mystring, "\\s(?=\\w*=)")))
```

```
                          x
1 nameinfo=Joe, Bloggs [[UK
2                  gender=2
3                   id1=6.2
4                     id2=7
5                      id=3
6                      id4=
7                     id5=0
8                total=20.6
```

Comment: If using `str_split_1()`, there's no need to include `unlist()`.